How can I add a link to org heading based on previous word?
Autocompletion can prompt a word used in the org mode file link. Imagine I have a heading:

heading1

then, further down, possibly many pages down, I type head and I get an autocompletion prompt with heading1. How can I convert the text heading1 into the link to the * heading1?
I have come up with a naive solution as below, but is there a better way to do it?
(defun insert-org-heading-link ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((w (word-at-point))
         (startpoint (search-backward w))
         (cpoint (point)))
    ;; remove word at point
    (replace-region-contents (+ 0 startpoint)
                             (+ (length w) cpoint)
                             (lambda ()
                               ""))
    ;; replace it with the link
    (replace-region-contents (+ 0 cpoint)
                             (+ 0 cpoint)
                             (lambda ()
                               (concat
                                "[[*"
                                w
                                "]["
                                w
                                "]]")))
    (forward-word)
    (forward-word)))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-z l") 'insert-org-heading-link)))


The key was to find the regexp used by org mode to find the headings in all-org-headings function
(defun all-org-headings ()
  "Return a list of org headings in the current buffer."
  (let ((matches nil))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward org-heading-regexp nil t)
        (push
         (buffer-substring-no-properties (line-beginning-position) (point))
         matches)))
    (reverse matches)))

(defun insert-org-heading-link ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((w (word-at-point))
           (startpoint (search-backward w))
           (cpoint (point))
           (all-headings (all-org-headings))
           (heading-names (cl-mapcar (lambda (h)
                                       (cl-second (split-string h "* ")))
                                     all-headings)))

      (message "HE %S"  all-headings)
      (message "HN %S"  heading-names)
      (if (member w heading-names)
          (progn
            (message "OK heading found %S" w)

            ;; remove word at point
            (replace-region-contents (+ 0 startpoint)
                                     (+ (length w) cpoint)
                                     (lambda ()
                                       ""))
            ;; replace it with the link
            (replace-region-contents (+ 0 cpoint)
                                     (+ 0 cpoint)
                                     (lambda ()
                                       (concat
                                        "[[*"
                                        w
                                        "]["
                                        w
                                        "]]")))
            (forward-word)
            (forward-word))

        (message "heading not found %s" w)))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-z l") 'insert-org-heading-link)))

improved version
(defun insert-org-heading-link ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((enteredw (word-at-point))
         (startpoint (search-backward enteredw))
         (cpoint (point))
         (heading-names (org-map-entries #'org-get-heading nil 'file))
         (the-heading (if (member enteredw heading-names)
                          enteredw
                        (ivy-completing-read (format "Select heading %S" enteredw)
                                             heading-names
                                             nil
                                             t
                                             enteredw)))
         (the-link (if the-heading
                       (concat
                        "[[*"
                        the-heading
                        "]["
                        the-heading
                        "]]"))))

    (if the-link
        (progn
          (replace-region-contents (+ 0 startpoint)
                                   (+ (length enteredw) cpoint)
                                   (lambda ()
                                     the-link))
          ;; go to the end of the link
          (search-forward "]]")))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-z l") 'insert-org-heading-link)))

even more improvements
(defun insert-org-heading-link ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((enteredw (word-at-point))
         (startpoint (search-backward enteredw))
         (cpoint (point))
         (heading-names (org-map-entries #'org-get-heading nil 'file))
         (the-heading (if (member enteredw heading-names)
                          enteredw
                        (completing-read (format "Select heading %s " enteredw)
                                         heading-names
                                         nil
                                         t
                                         enteredw)))
         (the-link (when the-heading
                     (format "[[*%s][%s]]" the-heading the-heading))))

    (when the-link
      (replace-region-contents (+ 0 startpoint)
                               (+ (length enteredw) cpoint)
                               (lambda ()
                                 the-link))
      ;; go to the end of the-link
      (search-forward "]]"))))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (local-set-key (kbd "C-z l") 'insert-org-heading-link)))


I think you are working too hard. E.g. all-org-headings can be written in a couple of lines: (defun all-org-headings () (org-map-entries #'org-get-heading nil 'file)) and you don't have to worry about the asterisks either. I don't have a suggestion on how to write the insert link function, but I have a question: what happens if the heading is not a single word? Is that not a case that you are interested in?

A single word is the simplest case. I have not progressed yet to more complex cases. That simple case allows me to play with the idea I have in mind about improving my workflow.

I have improved version

Better. Some more suggestions: the last two if conditionals have an empty else part  - I would rewrite those using when (and since the body of a when is an implicit progn, you can get rid of the explicit progn in the last case). I would also use format instead of concat: (format "[[*%s][%s]]" the-heading the-heading) is more readable IMO. On a less secure footing but for better portability, I would investigate replacing ivy-completing-read with the standard completing-read, but admittedly I don't know enough about it to be certain.

https://github.com/bigos/prelude/blob/84fdd33e76bad6bc1d5ef90c14339e51eeb0881b/personal/organised.el#L348  done

In my Emacs there is a menu item:  Org  / Hyperlinks / Insert Link C-c C-l, but is not exactly what I want.

Right - it is meant for interactive use: you do org-store-link at the target and then you do org-insert-link to insert a link that org-store-link squirreled away. It should be possible to use these two (with some modifications perhaps), but it requires jumping to the target in order to store a link to it and then coming back and defeating the interactivity of org-insert-link in order to insert it. I was going to suggest that, but I thought better of it... If I come up with a decent implermentation, I might post another answer.

https://github.com/bigos/githubkasten/blob/master/org-roam/20230604000628-finite_state_machine.org

I still get a 404... I can't even get to github.com/bigos/githubkasten/, let alone the rest.

proxy? or other problem? anyway it is example if https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine rewritten as org mode where links to next state were done using my new method
